# Date Picker show behind static table view cells

Tags: date, static, datepicker, uitableview, cell

Objective - C iOS Development. Hello all. I have a tableView with static cells in three groups. One of those cells is used to open a date picker object. The date picker opens, but appears behind the tableview cells. I'm unable to bring this object to the front. I'm looking for the same functionality as demonstrated when the keyboard launches - as in pushing the static table view cells up to display the keyboard. Any insight will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely need to post some code for anyone to be able to figure out what's wrong. If you're still starting out with iOS development, I'd recommend having a look at the free Sensible TableView framework. The framework has a cell that automatically handles displaying a date picker when tapped. You should find other frameworks too out there.